# Mysterious memory management

Tags: c, security, compiler-optimization

I am playing with simple buffer overflows. However, I found such compiler behaviour quite interesting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *arg1) {
    int authenticated = 0;

    char buffer[4];

    strcpy(buffer, arg1);

    if(authenticated) {
        printf("HACKED !\n");
    } else {
        printf("POOR !\n");
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    char* mystr = "abcdefghijkl";
    func(mystr);
    printf("THANK YOU!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What make me wonder is fact, that I need to assign 13-element buffer to arg1, not 5-element in order to overwrite authenicated variable.

GDB confirms that:

```
(gdb) print &authenticated 
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe75c
(gdb) print &buffer
$33 = (char (*)[4]) 0x7fffffffe750
```

The difference is 12 between addresses.
Why in this case compile isn't optimal?

In case of refactoring this functions, the difference is changing, but why not always the difference is 4 which seems to be the most optimal solution.

Thank You

Comment: It's *undefined* because your buffer doesn't have enough memory to copy the passed string. You can't expect (or rely) on it to overwrite other variable and expect a certain behaviour.

Comment: In terms of language specs, yes, it is undefined. But the asker clearly knows that, and he wants to know why his particular compiler exhibits the behavior it does.

Comment: But first compiler allocate memory for buffer and authenticated, and after that overfloow happens. So memory allocation should be consistent.

Comment: Once the compiler detects undefined behaviour, it is not only allowed to, but morally required to annoy the programmer in the maximum possible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between the variables is larger than you expect because they are being [aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) to [optimize performance](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html). Some operations require that memory location of a variable is a whole multiple of some number (usually the variable's size). So for example, an 8 byte `double` could be placed at location 0x1000 in memory, or 0x1008, but not 0x1004. Here's how your stack ends up looking (absent optimization etc.), with the numbers indicating the offset from the base of the stack:

```
-16: char[] buffer (4 bytes)
-12: padding (8 bytes)
 -4: int authenticated (4 bytes)
```

The int is understandably aligned at 4 bytes, but why is the char buffer being aligned at 16 bytes? In order to be able to exploit [SSE instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) for string operations. These require 16 bit memory alignment. Compiling the program with SSE disabled (`-mno-sse` with gcc) resulted in this layout:

```
 -8: char[] buffer (4 bytes)
 -4: int authenticated (4 bytes)
```

So that confirms that the extra padding was due to SSE.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

An optimising compiler will notice that buffer is not used after the strcpy, so the strcpy operation can be removed. It cannot have any detectable side effect without undefined behaviour.

An optimising (or non-optimising) compiler will notice that "authenticated" is always 0 and never changed unless there is undefined behaviour, and a compiler can always assume that there is no undefined behaviour. So it is absolutely fine to always print "POOR !\n".

So any conclusions you try to draw from your experiment, in the presence of undefined behaviour, are 100% unwarranted.

Comment: Presumably the author is compiling with optimization disabled - galvanize am I correct?

Comment: I hate answers like this. This C-standard-fundamentalist approach makes it impossible to analyze exploits that do work reliably in the real world. Program behavior is governed by more than just the C standard. ("How did the thief manage to get into the vault?" "Oh, he broke the law, so reality is meaningless and anything could happen".)